# How to install pyaudio?

Tags: python, pyaudio

My python version version is 3.9.0

I tried to install `pyaudio` but I get an error message.

I went to try a few different versions from an unofficial website, but none of them worked.

Every time I get an error msg that says:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64 (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64

this is there not any pyaudio version for python 3.9.0

Answer (score 2):

The message is pretty clear. PyPI does not yet have a Python 3.9 version of `pyaudio`. Christoph Gohlke's site [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs) does. I downloaded  it from there and it works. If it didn't work for you then you should show the `pip` command you issued and not just the error message you got. I used the command line

```
pip install D:\Users\BoarGules\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

Maybe you were expecting `pip` to know where the downloaded wheel was, without being told where to look?

And if you want to install `pyaudio` for Python 3.9 then it won't help to use a wheel named `PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`: the Python version is embedded in the filename and it says 3.6 not 3.9, so try again with the right file.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
pip install pipwin
```

then

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```